# numpy dot product returns NaN, Matlab equivalent does not return NaN

Tags: python, numpy

I have a vector of `beta=np.array([[1],[4],[0]])` and when I use `np.log` with this vector, I get this:

```
>>> np.log(beta)
array([[ 0.        ],
       [ 1.38629436],
       [       -inf]])
```

but when I use `np.dot` with this `beta` and an identity matrix it gives NaN instead of `1.38629436` as element at `[1,0]`.

```
>>> np.dot(np.eye(3),np.log(beta))
array([[ nan],
       [ nan],
       [-inf]])
```

I tried also this one:

```
>>> beta2 = np.log(beta)
>>> beta2
array([[ 0.        ],
       [ 1.38629436],
       [       -inf]])
>>> np.dot(np.eye(3),beta2)
array([[ nan],
       [ nan],
       [-inf]])
```

Matlab version of same multiplication does not return NaN. I would like to have the same in numpy. Any ideas?

Edit: I know basic linear algebra people thanks for that. My actual question was to manage to have a numpy equivalent for the dot product that does the same thing with the one with Matlab, which doesn't return NaN in the same case.

Answer (score 1):

The 3rd component of the vector is involved in all the products with rows of the matrix. Infinity times zero is indeterminate.  Python, like most languages, declares that to be not a number.

Answer (score 1):

i have recently experienced a case similar to this and it spurs this contribution. Using the np.dot() function of numpy will return NaN if for any chance at all one of the values of the vectors (ndarrays) you're trying to take the dot product of contain a NaN value for instance:

```
item1 = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,nan,7,8])
item2 = np.arange(12, 21)
np.dot(item1, item2)
```

`

This will return nan when you run the code because one value of item 1 contains a NaN value.
to get around this, just replace that nan value with a zero or appropriate value as it should be which in this case will be ;

```
item1 = np.arange(9)
item1[6] = 0
item2 = np.array(12, 21)
np.dot(item1, item2)
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the first element of

```
[[1 0 0]    [[0]
 [0 1 0]  *  [1.38629436]
 [0 0 1]]    [-inf]]
```

? Well, it's `1*0 + 0*1.38629436 + 0*-inf`. See that last part?

## `0*-inf`

All those nice theorems of linear algebra go straight out the window if you start trying to put infinities in your matrices. Heck, those theorems only approximately hold with finite floating-point numbers, since floating-point numbers and floating-point arithmetic can only approximate real numbers and real arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

The `dot` involves multiplying 'all' values, and summing one axis.  The equivalent to this dot is

```
np.einsum('ij,jk->ik`, np.eye(3), np.log(beta))
```

which can be evaluated with broadcasting as:

```
In [223]: np.eye(3)[:,:,None]*np.log(beta)[None,:,:]
Out[223]: 
array([[[ 0.        ],
        [ 0.        ],
        [        nan]],

       [[ 0.        ],
        [ 1.38629436],
        [        nan]],

       [[ 0.        ],
        [ 0.        ],
        [       -inf]]])
In [224]: (np.eye(3)[:,:,None]*np.log(beta)[None,:,:]).sum(axis=1)
Out[224]: 
array([[ nan],
       [ nan],
       [-inf]])
```

So the first `nan` comes from summing `[0,0,nan]`.

```
In [226]: 0*np.log(beta)
Out[226]: 
array([[  0.],
       [  0.],
       [ nan]])
```